# Freeing memory gives segmentation fault

Tags: c

I've been trying to work with structures, pointers and memory in C. 
I have created this structure

```
 typedef struct {
  int id;
  char *name;
} Object;
```

here is constructor

```
    void object_ctor(Object *o, int id, char *name)
{
    o->id = id;
    o->name = malloc(sizeof(name));
    if(sizeof(o->name)!=sizeof(name))
    {
        o->name=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(o->name, name);
    }
}
```

here is decleration of o1

```
  char tmp_name[] = "Hello 1";
Object o1;
object_ctor(&o1, 1, tmp_name);
```

here is destructor

```
void object_dtor(Object *o)
{
    if(o->name != NULL)
    {
        free(o->name);
        o->name = NULL;
    }

}
```

printing object

```
void print_object(Object *o)
{
    printf("ID: %d, NAME: %s\n", o->id, o->name);
}
```

calling copy

```
   Object copy;
   print_object(object_cpy(&copy, &o1));
```

and I´m trying create a copy of one structure to another (I have already constructed them).

```
Object *object_cpy(Object *dst, Object *src)
{
    if(src!=NULL)
    {
      const size_t len_str=strlen(src->name)+1;
      dst->name = malloc(10000000);
      dst->id = src->id;
      strncpy (dst->name, src->name,len_str);
    }

    if (strcmp(dst->name,src->name)!=0)
    {
      dst->name = NULL;
    }

    return dst;
}
```

But then when I'm trying to free both copy and original src I get a segmentation fault. I've been trying to run it through gdb and it said that I'm freeing same memory twice so I assume that the code for copying is wrong, but I don't know where.

And here is code that gives me segmentation fault

```
    printf("\nCOPY EMPTY\n");
   object_dtor(&copy);
    o1.id = -1;
   free(o1.name);
    o1.name = NULL;
    object_cpy(&copy, &o1);

    print_object(&copy);
    print_object(&o1);
```

I´m including these libraries

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

I'm using the `std=c99` flag for to compile.

Comment: `dst->name = malloc(10000000);`...you sure?

Comment: Why allocate a fixed (and really large) amount when you have the exact size you need to allocate (in `len_str`)?

Comment: `it said that I´m freeing same memory twice so i assume that the code for copying is wrong`..why? I'd say teh allocation is wrong.

Comment: You are also not checking the return value of `dst->name` for NULL. This will tell you if the `malloc` is successful. Since you have allocated such a large size, (10MB) there is a good chance that the `malloc` has failed

Comment: If `if (strcmp(dst->name,src->name)!=0)` evaluates to true, then you create a memory leak here: `dst->name = NULL;`. You should free the memory before setting the pointer to NULL.

Comment: You do not show us how you call the function, use the 2 variables and free the memory. Please provide this important information. Otherwise it is just guessing.

Comment: Ye that malloc i was really desperate so i tried fixed malloc. Before that i had malloc(sizeof(src->name))

Comment: `sizeof` of a pointer returns the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to.

Comment: @mimotej you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: Try running your program under `valgrind` and/or with `ElectricFence`. They are usually very good at pinpointing these kinds of problems.

Comment: Note that you can't simply do `free(&copy)` because `copy` wasn't allocated.  You could do `free(copy.name)`.  It isn't clear what you're doing with your stacked calls to functions you've not shown.  MCVE time!  Show the code that frees the information.  Note that if you call `object_cpy()` twice with the same destination pointer, you leak the memory allocated the first time (and 10 MB of memory is quite noticeable!).

Comment: I don't see any call of `free`

Comment: Edited I hope there is everything sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: `if(sizeof(o->name)!=sizeof(name))` What do you test here?

Comment: You misspelled `strlen` as `sizeof` in the "constructor".

Comment: Regarding `if (strcmp(dst->name,src->name)!=0)` in the copy function: unless your library is broken - and it won't be - that test will never be true.

Comment: You are first `free`ing `o1` and then copying `o1` to `copy`. Why is this?

Comment: In `object_ctor()`, you allocate `sizeof( name )` memory for `o->name`; the `sizeof` of a `char *` is the size of the pointer, not the length of the string. (Should be `strlen( name ) + 1`.) The subsequent `strcpy( o->name, name )` thus invokes undefined behavior, potentially trashing data structures that are located after the just allocated memory -- and after UB, all bets are off. Lacking a [mcve], all we could do is guess.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje I have test which tries to copy NULL into other pointer

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. That is a piece of code that we can be copy/paste/compile and run without doing guesswork.

Comment: @Jabberwocky added few more things this should be now runnable, sorry that it takes me so long to add other things but i´m taking it from much larger source code and i don´t want to give you unnecessary code that would be useless for you...

Comment: @mimotej be aware that a [mcve] is not a set of code snippets that can be compiled once stiched together. It's up to _you_ to stitch them together.

Comment: ...and while you're at it putting the MCVE together, please address the issues already pointed out, and make sure the problem actually still persists.

Comment: @Jabberwocky will keep it in mind for the next time. Your answer helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least a problem here:

```
void object_ctor(Object *o, int id, char *name)
{
  o->id = id;
  o->name = malloc(sizeof(name));
  if (sizeof(o->name) != sizeof(name))
  {
    o->name = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    strcpy(o->name, name);
  }
}
```

`sizeof(name)` is not the length of the string pointed by `name`. You need `strlen(name) + 1` (+1 for the NUL terminator).

And your test `if (sizeof(o->name) != sizeof(name))` is pointless, and I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

You probably want this:

```
void object_ctor(Object *o, int id, char *name)
{
  o->id = id;
  o->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);

  if (o->name != NULL)
    strcpy(o->name, name);
}
```

There are similar problems in `object_cpy`:

- pointless use of `strncpy`
- pointless allocation of a 10Mb buffer
- pointless test `strcmp(dst->name, src->name)`

You probably want this:

```
Object *object_cpy(Object *dst, Object *src)
{
  if (src != NULL)
  {
    const size_t len_str = strlen(src->name) + 1;
    dst->name = malloc(len_str);

    if (dst->name != NULL)
    {
      dst->id = src->id;
      strcpy(dst->name, src->name);
    }
  }

  return dst;
}
```

With these corrections following code works fine:

```
int main()
{
  char tmp_name[] = "Hello 1";
  Object o1, copy;
  object_ctor(&o1, 1, tmp_name);
  object_cpy(&copy, &o1);

  print_object(&copy);
  print_object(&o1);  

  object_dtor(&o1);
  object_dtor(&copy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Event if this is not directly an answer to your problem, I'll give you how I organize my code in order to avoid memory problem like yours.

First, it all resolve around a structure.
To each structure, if needed, I do a "Constructor" and a "Destructor".

The purpose of the constructor is simply to set the structure in a coherent state. It can't never fail (implying that any code that could fail, like malloc,  should not be in the constructor).
The purpose of the destructor is to clean the structure.

One little trick that I like to use is to put the constructor in a macro, allowing me to do something like 'Object var = OBJET_CONSTRUCTOR'.
Of course, it's not alway possible, it's up to you to be carreful.

For your code, it could be :

```
typedef struct {
    int  id;
    char *name;
} Object;

#define OBJECT_CONSTRUCTOR {.id   = -1,\ \\ Assuming -1 is relevant in your case, like an error code or a bad id value. Otherwise, it's useless.
                            .name = NULL}

void Object_Constructor(Object *self)
{
    Object clean = OBJECT_CONSTRUCTOR;

    *self = clean;
}

void Object_Destructor(Object *self)
{
    free(self->name);
}
```

Here we go.
How to use it is simple : You always begin by the constructor, and you alway end by the destructor. That's why it's useless to set the char pointer "name" to NULL in the destructor, because it should not be used after by any other function that the constructor.

Now, you can have "initialisation" function. You can do a plain initialisation (it is your constructor function), or a copy initialisation, etc etc
Just keep in mind that the structure have been called into the constructor. If not, it's the developer fault and you do not have to take that in count.

A behavior that can be nice is, in case of error, to not modify the structure.
Either the structure is entierly modified in succes, or not at all.
For complex structure that can fail at many point, you can do that by "swapping" the result at the end.

```
void Object_Swap(Object *first, Object *second)
{
    Object tmp = OBJECT_CONSTRUCTOR;

    tmp = *fisrt;
    *first = *second;
    *second = tmp;
}

bool Object_InitByPlainList(Object *self, int id, consr char *name)
{
    Object newly          = OBJECT_CONSTRUCTOR;
    bool   returnFunction = false;

    newly.id = id;
    if (!(newly.name = strdup(name))) {
        printf("error : %s : strdup(name) : name='%s', errno='%s'.\n", __func__, name, strerror(errno));
        goto END_FUNCTION;
    }

    // Success !
    Object_Swap(self, &newly);
    returnFunction = true;

    /* GOTO */END_FUNCTION:
    Object_Destructor(&newly);
    return (returnFunction);
}
```

It may be seem overcomplicated at the first glance, but that organization allow you to add more futur step "that can fail" cleanly.

Now, you can even do something this simply :

```
bool Object_InitByCopy(Object *dst, Object *src)
{
    return (Object_InitByPlainList(dst, src->id, src->name));
}
```

All you have to do is to say in the documentation :

- The first function to be called have to be "Object_Constructor"
- After the "Object_Constructor", only the "Object_Init*" function can be called.
- The last function to be call have to be "Object_Destructor"

That's all. You can add any "Object_*" function that you whant, like :

```
void Object_Print(const Object *self)
{
    printf("ID: %d, NAME: %s\n", self->id, self->name);
}
```

Hope this organization will solve your memory problem.

An example :

```
int main(void)
{
    Object test = OBJECT_CONSTRUCTOR;
    Object copy = OBJECT_CONSTRUCTOR;

    if (!Object_InitByPlainList(&test, 1, "Hello World !")) {
        // The function itself has logged why it has fail, so no need to add error printf here
        return (1);
    }

    Object_Print(&test);

    if (!Object_Copy(&copy, &test)) {
        return (1);
    }

    Object_Destructor(&test);
    Object_Destructor(&copy);
    return (0);
}
```